# Prediction in R doesn't work following rpart

Tags: prediction, rpart

I am working on a tree regression. Everything works fine with my code but I don't get the predicted values at all. Instead I get all values for my y variable (response variable). Here's the code:

## Separating in train and test set for data

```
`sample = sample.split(Data, SplitRatio = .80)
train = subset(Data, sample == TRUE)
test  = subset(Data, sample == FALSE)
varYTrain <- train[c(3)]
varYTest <- test[c(3)]
varXTrain <- train[c(5:27)]
varXTest <- test[c(5:27)]`
```

## Model

```
`x <- cbind(varXTrain,varYTrain)
fit <- rpart(as.matrix(varYTrain) ~ ., data = x, method="class")
summary(fit)`
```

## This one doesn't work as I don't get predictions based on test data set for an unknown reason

```
`predicted <- predict(fit, data=varXTest)
summary(predicted)`
```

I would also like in the end for the output to compare predicted values to real values in my dataset, can I do that?

Thank you very much and don't hesitate to ask me a question if I am not clear enough it's my first time posting.

Cheers